# In ReactJS How to save Child State in Parent state on destroying child?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I have a parent Component and two child Component as below:

ParentComponent:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Child1Comp } from "./Child1Comp";
import { Child2Comp } from "./Child2Comp";

export function ParentComp() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  const [parentState, setParentState] = useState({});
  const handleNextBtn = () => setStep((step) => step + 1);
  const handlePrevBtn = () => setStep((step) => step - 1);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`the parent state is: ${JSON.stringify(parentState)}`}</div>
      {step === 1 && (
        <Child1Comp
          step={step}
          parentState={parentState}
          setParentState={setParentState}
        />
      )}
      {step === 2 && (
        <Child2Comp
          step={step}
          parentState={parentState}
          setParentState={setParentState}
        />
      )}
      <br />
      <button
        id="nextBtn"
        name="nextBtn"
        onClick={handleNextBtn}
        disabled={step === 2}
      >
        Next
      </button>
      <button
        id="nextBtn"
        name="nextBtn"
        onClick={handlePrevBtn}
        disabled={step === 1}
      >
        Prev
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {`current step is : ${step}`}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child1Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Child1Comp({ step, parentState, setParentState }) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  const handleChange = (e) => setInputValue(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => setInputValue(parentState.child1), []);
  useEffect(
    () =>
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child1: inputValue
      })),
    [step]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      name:
      <input
        id="child1"
        name="child1"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child2Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Child2Comp({ step, parentState, setParentState }) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  const handleChange = (e) => setInputValue(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => setInputValue(parentState.child2), []);
  useEffect(
    () =>
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child2: inputValue
      })),
    [step]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      family:
      <input
        id="child2"
        name="child2"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

- In the parent Component, I have a step state for determining which child should be shown.
- Each child has itself state.

now I want when the user changes the step value by clicking on the Next button, the child state value save in the parent state, so I use this code in each child:

child1:

```
useEffect(
        () =>
          setParentState((parentState) => ({
            ...parentState,
            child1: inputValue
          })),
        [step]
      );
```

child2:

```
useEffect(
        () =>
          setParentState((parentState) => ({
            ...parentState,
            child2: inputValue
          })),
        [step]
      );
```

but when the step state changes in the parent Component, none of the top useEffect runs. and child state not save in parent state.:(

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-babbage-ocr9j?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use this solution:

i add saveStep state to parent component that is object of 'step,req,conf,action':

- step=> current step number.
- req=>bool value that show request to change step.
- conf=> bool value that show child state saved in parent or no.
- action=>next or prev button clicked.

step only when changed that req and conf both value is true.

ParentComponent:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Child1Comp } from "./Child1Comp";
import { Child2Comp } from "./Child2Comp";

export function ParentComp() {
  const [parentState, setParentState] = useState({});
  const [saveStep, setSaveStep] = useState({
    step: 1,
    req: false,
    conf: false,
    action: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (saveStep.req && saveStep.conf) {
      setSaveStep((saveStep) => ({
        step:
          saveStep.action === "next"
            ? saveStep.step + 1
            : saveStep.action === "prev"
            ? saveStep.step - 1
            : saveStep.step,
        req: false,
        conf: false
      }));
    }
  }, [saveStep]);

  const handleNextBtn = () =>
    setSaveStep((saveStep) => ({
      ...saveStep,
      req: true,
      action: "next"
    }));

  const handlePrevBtn = () =>
    setSaveStep((saveStep) => ({
      ...saveStep,
      req: true,
      action: "prev"
    }));

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`the parent state is: ${JSON.stringify(parentState)}`}</div>
      {saveStep.step === 1 && (
        <Child1Comp
          saveStep={saveStep}
          setSaveStep={setSaveStep}
          parentState={parentState}
          setParentState={setParentState}
        />
      )}
      {saveStep.step === 2 && (
        <Child2Comp
          saveStep={saveStep}
          setSaveStep={setSaveStep}
          parentState={parentState}
          setParentState={setParentState}
        />
      )}
      <br />
      <button
        id="nextBtn"
        name="nextBtn"
        onClick={handleNextBtn}
        disabled={saveStep.step === 2}
      >
        Next
      </button>
      <button
        id="nextBtn"
        name="nextBtn"
        onClick={handlePrevBtn}
        disabled={saveStep.step === 1}
      >
        Prev
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {`current step is : ${saveStep.step}`}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child1Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Child1Comp({
  saveStep,
  setSaveStep,
  parentState,
  setParentState
}) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  const handleChange = (e) => setInputValue(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => setInputValue(parentState.child1), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (saveStep.req) {
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child1: inputValue
      }));
      setSaveStep((saveStep) => ({ ...saveStep, conf: true }));
    }
  }, [saveStep.req]);

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      child1:
      <input
        id="child1"
        name="child1"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child2Component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Child2Comp({
  saveStep,
  setSaveStep,
  parentState,
  setParentState
}) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  const handleChange = (e) => setInputValue(e.target.value);

  useEffect(() => setInputValue(parentState.child2), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (saveStep.req) {
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child2: inputValue
      }));
      setSaveStep((saveStep) => ({ ...saveStep, conf: true }));
    }
  }, [saveStep.req]);

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      child2:
      <input
        id="child2"
        name="child2"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-babbage-ocr9j?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the state in the parent component and pass down getters and setters as props.
Something like this:

```
export function ParentComp() {
    const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
    const [child1Input, setChild1Input] = useState(null);
    const [child2Input, setChild2Input] = useState(null);
    
    return (
      <div>
      
        {step === 1 && (
          <Child1Comp
            input={child1Input}
            setInput={setChild1Input}
          />
        )}
        {step === 2 && (
          <Child1Comp
          input={child2Input}
          setInput={setChild2Input}
        />
        )}

        ...
```

Now the child components don't need no state variables or useEffects anymore, which means less risk of bugs and easier to understand the flow once your code grows.

```
export function Child1Comp({ input, setInput }) {

 return (
    <div>
      <br />
      name:
      <input
        id="child1"
        name="child1"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Of course, you can still keep the state in an object if you like, I hope you get the general idea though.

Comment: thanks, your solution is good but when the steps are many, for each child component should I have a "state" in the parent component that makes the parent not well-formed.

Comment: True, but like I say you can still put the state in one single object if you like, and still only keep it in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Keep watch on `inputValue` instead of `step` in `useEffect`

**Child1**

```
useEffect(
    () =>
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child1: inputValue
      })),
    [inputValue]
  );
```

**Child2**

```
useEffect(
    () =>
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child2: inputValue
      })),
    [inputValue]
  );
```

**Problem:**

> When you click on next/prev, the step value changes to 1 or 2 respectively in the parent. And accordingly, the respective child components get hidden and no longer exist on DOM. So that's why your `useEffect` code does not execute.

Comment: thanks for your solution and description, but when I use inputValue instead of step, for each change in input, the parent state will be affected. I now only when the user clicked on next/prev button, the child state saved in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The child component dismounts when the step changes and it cannot see when the step prop changes. Instead, you should watch the `inputValue` and set it to parent every time it changes.

```
  useEffect(
    () =>
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child2: inputValue
      })),
    [inputValue]
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use useEffect, there are missing dependencies in your useEffect (second parameter of useEffect, dependencies are in an array):

```
  useEffect(
    () => setInputValue(parentState.child2), 
   [parentState.child2] //If parentState.child2 change, useEffect function will be called
  );
  
  useEffect(
    () =>
      setParentState((parentState) => ({
        ...parentState,
        child2: inputValue
      })),
    [step, inputValue, setParentState] //If one of these variables change, useEffect function will be called
  );
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-kirch-ksjg6?file=/src/Child2Comp.js:235-478).

But a better way to do it is to handle changes like this:

```
import React from "react";

export function Child1Comp({ parentState, setParentState }) {
  const handleChange = (e) =>
    setParentState((oldParentValues) => ({
      ...oldParentValues, //Spread old parent states
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value // override child1 input value here
    }));

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      name:
      <input
        id="child1"
        name="child1"
        value={parentState.child1}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Woking example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-star-r69om?file=/src/Child1Comp.js)

**Note:** labels (name, familly, ...), and names (child1, child2, ...) are redundants and could be passed as props, in order to have a single ChildComponent. Like this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bohr-vdnru?file=/src/ParentComp.js)